# Общие атрибуты для фигур

Tags: css3, html5, классы, атрибуты, псевдоэлемент

```
<div class="main-circle">
  <div class="main-circle__item"></div>
  <div class="main-circle__item"></div>
  <div class="main-circle__item"></div>
  <div class="main-circle__item"></div>
  <div class="main-circle__item"></div>                     
</div>
```

Столкнулся с проблемой что не выводится фигура, я хотел создать для каждой фигуры одинаковые значения, а именно

```
.main-circle {
   background: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0px 5px 45px rgba(151, 175, 227, 0.1);
   border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;
}
```

Это я сделал , чтобы каждый раз новой фигуре "main-circle__item" не прописывать их, но теперь , когда я прописываю разные размеры фигур и их расположение , то они попросту не выводятся , что делать ?

```
.main-circle__item:nth-child(1) {
   position: absolute;
   width: 45px;
   height: 23px;
   left: 253px;
   top: 172px;
}
```

Comment: `.main-circle` - это контейнер. Надо заменить на `.main-circle__item` и фон сменить, белый же не видно...

Comment: у меня фон сайта не белый , он голубой , я его увижу

Comment: и зачем менять название , я так и не понял ?

Comment: Вы задаете CSS-правило для контейнера .main-circle, а Вам нужно задать общее правило для элементов-фигур .main-circle__item

Comment: то есть , по идее мне main-circle вообще не нужен ?

Comment: В CSS нет, не нужен. Разве только для того, чтобы задать свойство `position: relative`, если фигуры будут позиционироваться относительно контейнера, а не body.

Comment: хорошо , спасибо